# Верстка по сетке и выпадающее меню не клеится

Tags: menu, css

Вот с этого момента не получается,помогите новичку:

```
/*MENU====================*/
.sidebar nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.dropdown {
    display: none;
}

.sidebar nav ul li:hover .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
.sidebar nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #27dced;
    background: #060622;
    opacity: 0.6;
    display: block;
    width: 140px;
    height: 45;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
     margin-right: 20px;
}

.sidebar nav ul li a:hover {
    background: rgba(52, 68, 103, 0.08);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ftmj9oue/

Comment: @Justify, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Так не делается, как Вы сделали. Это нужно делать через jquery.

```
 $(".dropdown").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).css([
" display", "bloc"]);
      },
      function ()  $(this).css([
" display", "none"]);
      }
    );
```

Comment: А, вообще, на подобные вопросы отвечать не появляется желания из-за неряшливости с которой отправлен вопрос.

Comment: но речь шла о выпадающем меню с применением только css

Comment: Не стал смотреть "кашу", которую Вы отправили, отправляю свой пример. http://jsfiddle.net/hKS79/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vdvw9Lw4/